# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.infinispan.commons.marshall.jboss.ExtendedRiverMarshaller on Java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jboss, infinispan

I am trying to migrate to Java 11.0.2 from Java 8 but my tests are failing when I build(`gradle build`) the project with the below runtime exception. I can't find anything that has changed in Java 11 which can cause this issue. Any suggestions on how to get rid of it would be greatly appreciated.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.infinispan.commons.marshall.jboss.ExtendedRiverMarshaller
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.jboss.JBossMarshallerFactory.createMarshaller(JBossMarshallerFactory.java:49)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller$PerThreadInstanceHolder.getMarshaller(AbstractJBossMarshaller.java:314)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.jboss.AbstractJBossMarshaller.startObjectOutput(AbstractJBossMarshaller.java:90)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.VersionAwareMarshaller.startObjectOutput(VersionAwareMarshaller.java:110)
    at org.infinispan.marshall.core.VersionAwareMarshaller.objectToBuffer(VersionAwareMarshaller.java:75)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.AbstractMarshaller.objectToBuffer(AbstractMarshaller.java:41)
    at org.infinispan.commons.marshall.AbstractDelegatingMarshaller.objectToBuffer(AbstractDelegatingMarshaller.java:85)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.MarshallerAdapter.objectToBuffer(MarshallerAdapter.java:23)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.marshallCall(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:275)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.processSingleCall(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:293)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.invokeRemoteCommand(CommandAwareRpcDispatcher.java:147)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.invokeRemotelyAsync(JGroupsTransport.java:608)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.invokeRemotely(JGroupsTransport.java:532)
    at org.infinispan.topology.ClusterTopologyManagerImpl.fetchRebalancingStatusFromCoordinator(ClusterTopologyManagerImpl.java:161)
    at org.infinispan.topology.ClusterTopologyManagerImpl.start(ClusterTopologyManagerImpl.java:146)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:168)
    ... 134 more
```

Infinispan dependency mentioned in build.gradle file - `implementation group: 'org.infinispan', name: 'spring-boot-starter-infinispan', version: '1.0.0'`

Comment: It looks like JBoss Marshalling shipped with `spring-boot-starter-infinispan` isn't compatible with Java8. Is there a reason to use such an old version (it was released in 2016)?

Comment: No such reason actually but this dependency doesn't seem to have any newer versions than the 1.0.0 version which could be the reason that it is not compatible with Java 11.

Comment: The maven coordinates changed. For embedded caches you have https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/infinispan/infinispan-spring-boot-starter-embedded/ and for remote caches https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/infinispan/infinispan-spring-boot-starter-remote/. The latest release is 13.0.6.Final and the dev release is 14.0.0.Dev01.